# ACF Query Structure

Tags: wp-query

wonder if anyone can impart some knowledge on me. I have this query which displays feature image and link etc, but I'd like to add within it, that if a video exists use that code instead of the feature image.

So I was thinking I could add in a Custom Field with the embed code or link to the video in the ACF plugin which I'm using but not sure how to structure the query within the existing query, does that make sense?

```
<?php 
   // the query
   $the_query = new WP_Query( array(
    'category' => 'Publish',
    'category__not_in' => 36 ,
    'orderby' => 'rand',
    'order'   => 'ASC',
     'posts_per_page'=>'12'
   )); 
?>
<div class="">
<?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
  <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 reason">
    <h2 class="postheader"><?php the_title(); ?>    
    </h2>
<a target="blank" href="<?php the_field('url'); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('', array('class' => 'img-responsive')); ?></a>
    <br><?php the_excerpt(); ?> <a class="postlink" target="blank" href="<?php the_field('url'); ?>">Read more</a>
  </div>
  <?php endwhile; ?>
  <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
<?php else : ?>
  <p><?php __('No News'); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

So you want to check if a field from acf has a value and if thats true you want  to display it.
You can do it with this:

```
if( get_field( 'video' ) ) {

    ?>

        <video width="320" height="240" controls>

            <source src="<?php echo get_field( 'video' ); ?>" type="video/mp4">

        </video>

    <?php

}else{


    the_post_thumbnail('', array('class' => 'img-responsive'));

}
```

This checks the field with name 'video' for a value. If there is a value it will display the video. If there is no video it will display an image instead.

Here is the code added in your own code:

```
    <?php 
       // the query
       $the_query = new WP_Query( array(
        'category' => 'Publish',
        'category__not_in' => 36 ,
        'orderby' => 'rand',
        'order'   => 'ASC',
         'posts_per_page'=>'12'
       )); 
    ?>
    <div class="">
    <?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
      <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 reason">
        <h2 class="postheader"><?php the_title(); ?>    
        </h2>
    <a target="blank" href="<?php the_field('url'); ?>"><?php 

if( get_field( 'video' ) ) {

    ?>

        <video width="320" height="240" controls>

            <source src="<?php echo get_field( 'video' ); ?>" type="video/mp4">

        </video>

    <?php

}else{

    the_post_thumbnail('', array('class' => 'img-responsive'));

}?></a>
        <br><?php the_excerpt(); ?> <a class="postlink" target="blank" href="<?php the_field('url'); ?>">Read more</a>
      </div>
      <?php endwhile; ?>
      <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
    <?php else : ?>
      <p><?php __('No News'); ?></p>
    <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
```

You still need to change the ACF field name of 'video' in the code to your field name.